# Taking a lot of time to receive boot complete broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I'm having an app that must run when android system start-up, I used the usual way of registering the broadcast and receiving it:

in **manifest.xml**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.automation.isolace"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="1.3"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

   <application
   .
   .
   .
      <receiver
        android:name="com.automation.standards.BootCompletedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
        .
        .
        .
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And in `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MConn", "BOOT_COMPLETED received");
    }
}
```

then, when the device boots, the app supposed to receive the `boot_completed` broadcast immediately, but the result varies across different devices, at some devices the app receives it immediately and in others it receives it after a while, this while can be a second or two and at some devices it reaches about 10 seconds, and the problem here is that the app must run before the home screen UI appears, so it has to receive the broadcast immediately.

As appears in the code in manifest, I tried to give the broadcast the most high priority ever, but the issue is still on the table.

So, what are the possibilities that can make this happen, and is there is a way to solve that? and is there is a way to overcome that in a work-around way (like preventing the device from displaying the screen for a while or blocking the system from starting its home activity layout)?

Comment: @MikeM. thank you. So how to know which broadcasts are likely to run first?!! is there is a specific constant order?!!